# MySQL Join with min and max date

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables

```
profile
--------
id
name
```

```
Profile_dates
-------------- 
id
profile_id
entry_date
```

The tables have 1 to many relationships

I want to get min and max entry_date for each profile like

```
id
name
profile_dates.first_date
profile_dates.last_date
```

the profiles_dates table can have thousands of entries per profile. The simple join was very expensive for me. Is there another option?

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY. MIN(), MAX().

Answer (score 1):

simply join two tables and group by id:

```
select p.id , name , min(pd.entry_date) first_date, max(pd.entry_date) last_date
from profiles p 
left join Profile_dates pd
 on p.id = pd.id
group by p.id , name
```

Comment: simple join is very expensive, the profile_dates table can potentially have thousands of entries per profile.

Comment: @U.A.Malik , that's your best bet , you may wanna add an index for  entry_date column for best performance

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes subquery performance is far better than left join. Please try this simple solution.

```
id, name, (select min(entry_date) from  Profile_dates pd where pd.profile_id=p.id) first_date,
(select max(entry_date) from  Profile_dates pd where pd.profile_id=p.id) last_date
from profile p
```

Comment: I agree that this might perform better than the other answer, but much less readable. I would like to see the execution plan for both of these answers.

Comment: Well, actually this query didnt perform any better then a join. 
I am going to approach the problem in a different way. 
Maybe I will cache this query results or maybe change my DB structure to have first and late dates. Thanks for your time anyway.